# How to keep a time gap between each POST request when multiple requests are involved

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 14. I'm creating a file uploader component with "cancel an upload in progress" feature. Assume that I've dragged and dropped 4 image files in my uploader component and now I'm going to press the upload button from UI. On click following method will be called.

```
  uploadFiles() {
    this.droppedFileArray.map((item) => {
      item.fileEntry.file((file: File) => {
        if (this.isFileSizeAllowed(file.size)) { // file size validation
          if (this.files.length < 6) { // number of files validation
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('excel', file);
            const headers = new HttpHeaders({
              'x-request-id': 'file_upload_' + new Date().getTime(), // using timestamp for uniqueness
            });

            timer(10000) // 10 sec timer to mimic slow internet
              .pipe(
                switchMap(() =>
                  this.http.post(
                    'http://localhost:8090/my-service/file-uploader/upload',
                    formData,
                    {
                      headers: headers,
                      responseType: 'json',
                    }
                  )
                )
              )
              .pipe(catchError((err) => this.handleError(err)))
              .subscribe((res: any) => {
                // display message: 'File successfully uploaded',
              });
          } else {
              // display message: 'File limit exceeded.',
          }
        } else {
            // display message: 'file is too big',
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

**Other information:**

`droppedFileArray` is an array of objects, where each object is information about file:
[image]

**Problem with my code:**

1. My code is uploading all selected files in one go even when I'm using `timer(10000)` from `RxJs`.

**Requirement:**

1. There should be gap of 10 or more sec between each upload. I want this delay so that i can mimic a slow internet and test my cancel upload functionality later.

Comment: Did you try mimic using [Chrome slow connection](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/how-to-perform-network-throttling-in-chrome#:~:text=Press%20Control%2BShift%2BJ%20or,set%20to%20Online%20by%20default.&text=From%20the%20dropdown%20menu%20highlighted,above).

Comment: Yes I'm aware of throttling also. But still I need to keep a gap between each request

Answer (score 0):

It is emmetting all file at the same time because, you generate observables that not depends on the other. For each file make a call after a timer.

You can use interval with mergeMap from rxjs to handle this :

```
uploadFiles() {
    // 1. filter files that are too big and files number
    if (this.droppedFileArray.length > 6) {
      return // 'File limit exceeded.',
    }

    if (this.droppedFileArray.filter(file => !this.isFileSizeAllowed(file.size)).length) {
      return // 'file is too big',
    }

    // 2. upload files

    interval(10000)
      .pipe(
        map((index) => this.droppedFileArray[index]),
        mergeMap((file) => {
          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('excel', file);
          const headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'x-request-id': 'file_upload_' + new Date().getTime(), // using timestamp for uniqueness
          });
          return this.http.post(
            'http://localhost:8090/my-service/file-uploader/upload',
            formData,
            {
              headers: headers,
              responseType: 'json',
            }
          ).pipe(
            catchError((err) => this.handleError(err)),
            tap(() => {
              // 'File successfully uploaded',
            })
          )
        })
      ).subscribe({
        complete: () => {
          // 'All files uploaded',
        }
      });
  }
```

Moreover, I recently find this post [abour rxjs operators](https://indepth.dev/posts/1114/learn-to-combine-rxjs-sequences-with-super-intuitive-interactive-diagrams#combinelatest) , it easy to understand how the operators works.

Comment: Error 400 Bad request

Comment: Could you add more details about the request ? Is your request working with your code before ? And are the requests coorectly send at 10s interval?